# How can I obtain a SDE with an advection function that contains the difference in covariates?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, discretization-and-quantization

Suppose that $\mathbf{s}(t)\in S$ denotes the spatial location of a process at time $t$. Further, let $\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{s}(t))$ denote covariates at the location $\mathbf{s}(t)$. My goal is to write an SDE for the process that can be discretized in the following way:
$$\mathbf{s}(t) - \mathbf{s}(t-dt) = \mathbf{a}'(\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{s}(t)) - \mathbf{x}(\mathbf{s}(t-dt))) + \text{noise},$$
where $\mathbf{a}$ are advection coefficients constant with respect to time. How may I formulate the SDE such that I can get the desired discretization? Right now, I'm considering
$$\frac{d\mathbf{s}(t)}{dt} = \frac{\mathbf{a}'d\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{s}(t))}{dt} + \frac{\text{noise}}{dt},$$
but I'm not sure that I'm using the correct approach/order when deriving the advection component to get the desired approach.

Comment: This might also fit better in https://physics.stackexchange.com/ since I think you are looking for a physics-based derivation.

Comment: ignoring the noise for a second which actually forces $s(t)$ to be non-differentiable, by chain rule you get $$d(x(s(t)))/dt=x'(s(t))ds/dt.$$

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thank you for your suggestion about the physics stack exchange. I'll give that a go. Just to clarify on your second comment: $\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{s}(t))$ are covariates of the process at time $t$, so we wouldn't need to apply chain rule, right? I suppose the notation of $\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{s}(t))$ is a bit confusing, but I'm treating $\mathbf{y}(t)$ as an index for the covariates $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: I did the chain rule because we then get the sde $$\frac{ds(t)}{dt}=\frac{1}{1-a'x'(s(t))}dB_{t}.$$ But this is just a suggestion because I don't know what your particular situation is.

Comment: I see. Thank you for all of your help, Thomas!